# C++ If-else Branch wont produce an output

Tags: c++, if-statement, branch

hope all is well. I was working on some code (C++) that would determine the season depending on the users input. The user is meant to type in a valid month and date in a year and from that the code is supposed to determine the season. Per instructions provided by my professor:

The dates for each season are:
Spring: March 20 - June 20
Summer: June 21 - September 21
Autumn: September 22 - December 20
Winter: December 21 - March 19

I was working on Spring for now, and this is the code I have. Just a little heads up, when inputting values March 20 - March 31, the code runs to my expectation and prints what is being looked for. However, when I type in any value such as June 1 - June 20 the program compiles, but it does not produce an output.

Here is the link to my code: https://repl.it/repls/FlippantAgileTheory

And here is the code:

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string inputMonth;
    int inputDay;

    cin >> inputMonth;
    cin >> inputDay;

    if (inputMonth == "March" || inputMonth == "June") {
        if (inputMonth == "March") {
            if (inputDay > 19 && inputDay < 32) {
                cout << "Spring\n";
            }
            else if (inputMonth == "June") {
                // this is the aspect of the code that doesn't work
                if ((inputDay > 0) && (inputDay < 21)) { 
                    cout << "Spring\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look carefully how `if` and `else` match. Or use a debugger to go through each line of your program.

Answer (score 1):

The probable reason why good code needs to be well indented.
You can easily debug it if you indent it properly

Like-

```
if(inputMonth=="March"){
   ...
}
else if(inputMonth=="June"){
   ...
}
```

Also I think it would be better to use switch-cases here for the months differently other than using nested if-else statements that much, use the month  names in an enum class for better code quality.

Comment: You still need to convert a string representation to the enum.

Comment: Yes but it was more about refactoring the code into more logical parts, that's why i suggested it.

Comment: switch statement is not a refactoring, it is also considered a bad practice. You advice out of two evels select both.

Comment: I just meant the enum class for the last comment as you mentioned it ,at the same time I advised every possible solution out there that can be applied in this case , my bad if my answer was not so clear or correct.

Comment: Don't advise "to use switch-cases": just provide a working snippet that supports your idea. You may find it not that easy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem becomes obvious if you add proper formatting.

All your print statements are within the block

```
if (inputMonth == "March") {
    // ...
}
```

That means that no other month can cause any printing.

You probably meant

```
if (inputMonth == "March") {
    // ...
}
else if (inputMonth == "June") {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important to make sure the code is properly formatted.

In your case, I assume what you meant to implement is:

```
if (inputMonth == "March" || inputMonth == "June"){

    if (input == "March") {
        if (inputDay > 19 && inputDay < 32){
            cout << "Spring\n";
         }
    }

    else if (input == "June") {
        if ((inputDay > 0) && (inputDay < 21)){ 
            cout << "Spring\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Just making changes to your brackets placement to make sure your if and else match properly will get the code working in no time.

I hope this helps.